# Assign layout-level parameter to all jade template views

Tags: templates, node.js, express, pug

I'm  making my first *Node* site using *Express* and *Jade* and I'm puzzled as to how routing works. I've got  a simple route for my index:

```
var routes = require('./routes');
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

and the corresponding definition of in **./routes/index.js**:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Test', ua: req.headers['user-agent']})
};
```

If I wanted to assign the `ua` parameter to all my views, how would I do that? I'd like to not have to specify that in each route file, but I'm not finding the documentation for how to assign layout-level parameters so they are available in all my jade views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a dynamic helper:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
    ua: function (req, res) {
        return req.headers['user-agent'];
    }
});
```

Edit: link to [relevant section of the docs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app.dynamichelpers%28%29)

***Note: dynamicHelpers are deprecated in Express 3***

Comment: thanks. the docs are really hard to use. the fact that you had to link the entire guide shows this.

Comment: Now that you point it out, I did try to link to the dynamicHelpers section. Looks like it's either not possible or I messed up, sorry!